# Grab frame from .mov file using DirectShow.net

Tags: c#, .net, directshow.net

How to grab frame from .mov file in c#.net by using DirectShow.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DirectShow and DirectShow.NET don't make it any special with `.MOV` files. You typically create a filter graph with a Sample Grabber filter that you manage, and its callback gives you frames of video stream that passes through.

You might want to look at DxScan sample in DirectShow.NET, \Samples\Editing\DxScan. It grabs frames from a given movie file.

> A sample application scanning a media file looking for black frames
>
> Most of the work is done in ISampleGrabberCB.BufferCB.  See the comments 
>   there.  Also, the algorithm used to scan for black frames isn't as efficient
>   as it could be.  However, the samples gives you an idea of how this could be
>   done.

Comment: DxScan application throws an exception, when i try to scan any mov file, maybe i need to change Grabber config? currently it is



AMMediaType media;
media = new AMMediaType();
media.majorType = MediaType.Video;
media.subType = MediaSubType.RGB24;
media.formatType = FormatType.VideoInfo;
hr = sampGrabber.SetMediaType( media );

Comment: It all depends on parsers/decoders installed. They are supposed to be capable to lead you from file to RGB 24, and if they are unable to then you have a problem like this.

Comment: so you mean, that i need to install quick time or something else ?